# IBM's Bluemix Toolchain process hangs on completion

Tags: containers, ibm-cloud, dockerfile, devops

I've built my container multiple times successfully, as noted by the image below. Each time it remains on 99% for > 20+ mins AFTER saying 'Finished: SUCCESS' in the logs. It never makes it past this. I cant kick off the deploy phase until the build registers completion. Is there a way to get past this hang?

[image: Bluemix Log Output]

I've got no notable errors in the console. The build is based on the registry.ng.bluemix.net/ibmnode:latest image, runs an apache2 server with some Node.js processes that run during the build phase. And lastly, it kicks off a bash script to run apache2 in the foreground.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked my toolchain and wasn't able to reproduce this problem.  Please try again, it might have been a transient issue with the toolchains.

If the problem persists, it might have to do with how you have your build script setup.  If you are spawning processes and leaving them running, that could be stopping the build from finishing.